# SQL - The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I created a trigger when the table named 'Device Log' will be insert data, I tried the 'Enable Promotion of Distributed Transaction' into false. I already did the MSDTC. but the error keeps showing.

> Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure INSERT_EmployeeTimeInOut, Line 35 [Batch Start Line 48]

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.[INSERT_EmployeeTimeInOut]
    ON [dbo].[DeviceLog]
AFTER INSERT
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @tCustomerID VARCHAR(30)
    ,@tSerialNumber VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@tLogType VARCHAR(2)
    ,@tLogDate DATETIME
    ,@tIPadd VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@tDeviceName VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@tManufacturer VARCHAR(MAX)




    SELECT @tCustomerID = INSERTED.AccessNumber 
    , @tSerialNumber = INSERTED.SerialNumber
    ,@tLogType = INSERTED.LogType
    ,@tLogDate = INSERTED.RecordDate
    FROM INSERTED


    SELECT @tIPadd = IPAddress 
    ,@tDeviceName = DeviceName
    ,@tManufacturer = Manufacturer 
    FROM AMA_DB.[dbo].TDevice where SerialNumber = @tSerialNumber

    

BEGIN
    
        INSERT INTO [LNKDB].MTPD.dbo.[tblTime](UserNo,LogDate,LogTime,TerminalID,LogStatus,PCName,DeviceUsed,poststamp,poststamp_results)
        SELECT @tCustomerID,REPLACE(convert(DATE, @tLogDate), '-',''),REPLACE(convert(varchar, @tLogDate, 8), ':',''),CONCAT(@tSerialNumber,'-',@tIPadd)
        ,CASE WHEN @tLogType = 'IN' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,@tDeviceName,CONCAT(@tManufacturer,'-','FACE'),GETDATE(),GETDATE()

END
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "did the MSDTC" and if you restarted SQL Server services on either side after those changes? If you're just logging this activity in another place, have you considered logging it in an extra _local_ logging table, and then having some other background process _not involved in the original transaction_ move the rows over to the other server? Generally triggers should be short and sweet with no external dependencies. As an aside, your trigger is broken, as it assumes that only single-row inserts will ever happen (maybe the app won't do that; a user might).

Comment: (On that latter point, read Brent Ozar's [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/).)